# How to evaluate an aspect based sentiment analysis model?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have a model X that takes a review and predict the position of the aspect and the polarity:

```
input: Serves really good sushi. (review)
output: sushi > Positive (aspect > polarity).
```

I've seen that this task in the literature has many different ways to be evaluated. Also, some datasets/models include the sentiment words (in our example, '`really good`').

Anyway, given the above input & output, how can I evaluate my model? on aspect words? on polarity? should I validate that the polarity referred to the correct aspect before counting it as a hit?

Comment: That is also my question, did you get any answer?

Comment: Yes @MahdiAmrollahi , I'll answer it now.

Comment: What exactly mean ```sushi > pos ```? Do you mean, the polarity of that sentence about ```sushi``` is ```positive```? Is that it?

Comment: @MahdiAmrollahi the polarity of the aspect `sushi` is `positive`.  In ABSA, the polarity is per Aspect, not per sentence. If you're working on an ASBA task, I'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long literature review, I was able to answer my question:

There are several tasks, so it depends:

- **Aspect extraction**: measure the accuracy (or any other metric,
  usually F1 score) of detecting `sushi`
- **Opinion extraction**: measure
  the accuracy of detecting `good`
- **Sentiment classification**: measure
  the accuracy for correctly classifying `sushi` as `Positive`
- **End-to-end ABSA**: the accuracy will be measured based on two steps, 1 and 3. If the model detects the aspect and the sentiment correctly, then this is a correct case. If the model missed one of them, the case will be considered wrong. *This category is the answer to my above question*

5. I've seen in SemEval shared tasks (2014, 2015, 2016) that they have another task which is **category classification of aspects**. For instance, considering the example above, a model should give `sushi` a `food` label.

Thus, it depends on what do you want to do exactly, or what is your task. I hope I didn't miss anything.